# Page break in iOS adds an extra blank pages when converting HTML to pdf

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, objective-c

When converting HTML to pdf in UIWebView, i want to add a page break, so i uses media queries

```
<style type="text/css" media="print"> 
     .pagebreak { display:block; page-break-before:always; }
</style>
```

But when i add it to HTML element, it adds an extra blank pages in document(pdf) where i add a page break and then starts that element from next page.
I want to remove that blank page which is added while using media queries.

Note: I already go through all the available solution on stackoverflow (including, adding a page break class to H1), but they doesnot work.

** Tested on iOS7 **

Any help it greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @Tim Walsh: No.Till now, i didn't get any solution and i am still looking for it.

Comment: any luck with the issue @MohitPandey